# Parameters in AJAX request in HAML

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra, haml

Here is fragments of my HAML view:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src  => "assets/application.js"}

:javascript
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#post_action_trigger').click(function(event) {
          $.get('/how?name=some', function(data) {
            $('#answer').html(data);
          });
        });
      } );

%body
   %form 
        %label{:for => 'name'} Name:
        %input{:type => 'text', :name => 'name', :class => 'text'}

        %label{:for => 'notes'} Notes:
        %input{:type => 'text', :name => 'notes', :class => 'text'}

        %div{:id => 'post_action_trigger'}
```

Now when I'm clicking on 'post_action_trigger'-div my javascript send ajax request '/how?name=some'.  How can I pass input-fields values into this ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var serializedData =$('form').serialize();
$.get('/how?' + serializedData, function(data) {
```

`serialized` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Description: Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

Comment: @demas. You can ask for it on `meta`... :) thanks for the feedback.